# How to stop install script from executing when curl fails with a 404 error?

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I'm trying to run asp.net project on linux Mint.  I'm following below instructions:
https://blog.tonysneed.com/2015/05/25/develop-and-deploy-asp-net-5-apps-on-linux/

but when I'm trying to put this command:

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.sh | DNX_BRANCH=dev sh && source ~/.dnx/dnvm/dnvm.s
```

and then I'm getting following message:

```
sh: 1: 404:: not found
```

Do you know maybe what causing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your pipeline is not working properly because `curl` is failing, throwing the 404 error into stdout which feeds into `sh`.  We can solve this by altering your command sequence slightly:

```
curl --fail -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.sh \
  -o dnvminstall.sh && DNX_BRANCH=dev sh dnvminstall.sh && \
  source ~/.dnx/dnvm/dnvm.s && rm -f dnvminstall.sh
```

- `--fail` option to forces `curl` to exit non-zero upon a 404
- `-o` downloads the install script into a local file
- `&&` instead of `|` chains the commands in such a way that we stop when `curl` fails
- `rm -f dnvminstall.sh` at the end cleans up the downloaded script.

---

See this post:

[How to make curl exit non-zero status when HTTP status is not a 200](https://superuser.com/questions/590099/can-i-make-curl-fail-with-an-exitcode-different-than-0-if-the-http-status-code-i)

Comment: I found right now that url:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.sh
is not available anymore.
Do you know any other method to install DNVM?